# Stackdriver Error Email Notifications not Sending

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I want to get notifications by email for errors on my google cloud service.

It seemed pretty easy to setup. I just hit turn on notifications in Error Reporting in Stackdriver for all services (I only have 1 service).

I created some errors for testing, but didnt receive any emails.

Went into alert policy and profiles and added email notification as a channel. Still not notifications via email.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: An email is sent as a result of an alert being raised.  Do you see a history of alerts having been raised ... each one should have sent an email.  If you see no alerts, then there wouldn't have been emails.

Comment: Yes there were new errors that I made and were listed.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to check if the notification is actually being sent is to post a test error message manually to the error reporting API.

First, verify that error notifications are available for the project, and then, run the following command on your cloud shell:

```
gcloud beta error-reporting events report --verbosity=debug --service Manual --service-version test1 \
  --message "java.lang.TestError: msg
    at com.example.TestClass.test(TestClass.java:51)
    at com.example.AnotherClass(AnotherClass.java:25)"
```

You should receive an email from StackdriverNotifications-noreply@google.com

If you receive the notification for the test, your other errors might be misconfigured. If you don't receive it, then you might need to verify that the noreply address is not being blocked by your provider/filters.